# Применение в другом классе переменной в C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс простой Player:

```
// Класс игрока
public class Player
{
    private string _name;
}
```

Также, например, хочу сделать класс Enemy, в котором хочу применить переменную _name(Только в этом классе). Вопрос, мне надо в классе Enemy наследоваться от Player или есть другое решение?

Дополнение:
Например, у нас есть класс "монетка" и когда игрок подбирает монетку, то в классе "монетка" вызывается метод, который выводит следующее - "Игрок {_name (Из класса Player) подобрал монетку}". Как это реализовать максимально правивльно?

Comment: Наследование, это когда вы хотите, чтоб то, что есть в этом классе, было также и в другом классе, без необходимости повторной реализации (если это класс), например, Кот, Собака, Кролик, все это "Животное", у них есть общие данные, например они могут "Кушать", у них есть показатель возраста, тип животного и так далее, так зачем надо по 100 раз писать реализацию метода питания, если мы можем это задать в одном, базовом классе и от него наследоваться? В вашем случае, `Enemy` является игроком? У него должна быть такая-же реализация, что и у игрока? Если да, то наследуйтесь.

Comment: Мне нужно просто использовать переменную _name, например в классе, который вообще не связан с этим классом

Comment: Начнём с того, что `_name` в вашем коде не _переменная_, а _поле_ класса.

Answer (score 4):

Проектирование классов ООП строится на простых логических цепочках.

Спросите себя, может ли враг `Enemy` быть прямым наследником игрока `Player`? Игрок `Player` в теории должен управлять игроком, взаимодействовать с другими игроками, быть хорошим и иметь другие характеристики. Класс `Enemy` как по мне всем этим не обладает, к тому же изменения `Player` могут отразиться на `Enemy`, поэтому тут ошибка логического проектирования.

После лирического отступления, напрямую к способам.

***Можно просто задублировать, ведь логически это разные сущности.***

В этом в принципе нет ничего плохого, ведь лучше задублировать сейчас, чем в будущем при переписывании страдать от собственного наследования и разделять эти сущности.

```
public class Player
{
    private string _name;
}

public class Enemy
{
    private string _name;
}
```

***Можно выделить общего родителя, чтобы сохранить логику.***

Однако учтите, что наследоваться можно только от одного класса. Обратите внимания на измененный модификатор доступа на `protected`.

```
public class Character
{
    protected string _name;
}

public class Player : Character
{
}

public class Enemy : Character
{
}
```

***Можно избавляться от зависимостей с помощью интерфейсов.***

В основном это нужно для того, чтобы обработка в методах шла одинаковым образом.

```
public interface ICharacter
{
    string name { get; set; }
}

public class Player : ICharacter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Enemy : ICharacter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда можно обрабатывать сущности так:

```
List<ICharacter> list = new List<ICharacter>()
{
    new Player(), new Enemy()
}
foreach(ICharacter character in list)
    Console.WriteLine(character.name);
```

***Есть еще всякие паттерны проектирования, но это уже другая история.***

```
public class Player
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Enemy 
{
    private Player player;
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Enemy(Player player) { this.player = player; }

    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Враг {this.name} была атакован игроком {player.name}");
    }
}
```

P.S. Судя по описанию, общий родительский класс вполне подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class Unit {

    public string Name { get; protected set; } // Можно запросить, но нельзя изменить из вне Unit и его наследников
    protected UnitControl control; // Доступно только для Unit и его наследников
    // Дольнейшие общие переменные

    public abstract void Dead (); // Функция не реализована, но обязательна для реализации у наследников
    // Дольнейший общий функционал
}

public class Player : Unit {

    public Player () {
        Name = "Hero";
        control = new PlayerControl();
    }

    public override void Dead () {
        // GameOver
    }
}

public class Enemy : Unit {

    public Enemy () {
        Name = "Monster";
        control = new EnemyControl();
    }

    public override void Dead () {
        // Drop Loot
    }
}

public class Test {
    
    public Test () {
        Enemy NewEnemy = enw Enemy();
        Console.WriteLine(NewEnemy.Name); // можно
        NewEnemy.Name = "Gollum"; // нельзя
    }
}
```

`Name` публичная переменная. `get` позволяет обратиться к ней кому угодно, а `protected set` позволит задавать это поле только самому `Unit` и тем, кто от него наследуется, защищая от внешнего редактирования.

Если `Enemy`, родственный классу `Player`, то не `Enemy` наследуется от `Player`, а они оба наследуются от некого общего `Unit`. `abstract` значит, что `Unit` не может быть создан сам по себе (`new Unit()`), он как болванка описывающая функции.

А вообще вам бы почитать про [наследование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance). Узнаете много интересного, чем будете пользоваться всегда и везде.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятны конкретные мотивы этого. Если поле _name должно быть во всех классах-сущностях, описывающих персонажей, то есть смысл определить вот таких образом:

```
public class Player
{
     protected string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Enemy : Player
{
     //здесь будет доступно поле Name
}
```

Если вы имели в виду что-то другое, то сформулируйте задачу чуть более конкретно в комментарии.

Comment: Но если я хочу использовать _name только в том классе, который вообще не связан с классом Player.

Comment: Подробнее раскройте смысл "только в том классе, который вообще не связан с классом Player". Т.е. использовать _name ТОЛЬКО в классе Enemy? В таком случае, просто объявите там такое поле.

Comment: Например, у нас есть класс "монетка" и когда игрок подбирает монетку, то в классе "монетка" вызывается метод, который выводит следующее - "Игрок {_name (Из класса Player) подобрал монетку}". Как это реализовать максимально праивльно?

Comment: @ion А почему "монетка", должна отвечать за отображение информации о том, что подобрал игрок? У вас изначально логическая цепочка нарушена. Почитайте про SOLID, там есть пункт, называется "Принцип единственной ответственности", который говорит о том, что объект должен реализовывать только одну логику, быть ответственным только за что-то одно. Так почему ваша монетка отвечает за действия игрока?